# Efficient coding to count capital characters in file

Tags: bash

I want to count all the capital characters A-Z from a file.

I take the file as an argument and then i search the whole file for each letter and sum my result. My code is working fine, but is there another way to make it more efficient, without using loop?

```
sum=0
for var in {A..Z}
do
    foo="$(grep -o $var "$1"| wc -l)"
    sum=$((sum+foo))
done
```

I tried to do it like this but it gives me wrong results, because its counting spaces and end line.

```
cat  "$1" | wc -m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single grep command similar to what you're already doing:

```
grep -o "[A-Z]" "$1" | wc -l
```

Comment: `tr` is also good here: `tr -dc 'A-Z' < "$1" | wc -c` -- tr is a pure filter can must read from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

We can really avoid using multiple programs for counting capital letters in a file, this could done easily with a single `awk` and it will save us some cycles and should be FASTER too.

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  count+=gsub(/[A-Z]/,"&")
}
END{
  print "Total number of capital letters in file are: " count
}
'  Input_file
```

In case you want to run it as a script which takes Input_file as an argument change Input_file to `$1` too.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code, only for explanation purposes  not for running(following one).

```
awk '                                                                   ##Starting awk program here.
{
  count+=gsub(/[A-Z]/,"&")                                              ##Creating a variable named count whose value will be keeping adding to itself, each time a substitution done from gsub.
                                                                        ##where gsub is awk out of the box function to substitute.
                                                                        ##Using gsub I am substituting each capital letter with itself and adding its count to count variable.
}
END{                                                                    ##Starting END block for this awk program. which will be executed once Input_file is done with reading.
  print "Total number of capital letters in file are: " count           ##Printing total number of capital letters which are there in count variable.
}
'  Input_file                                                           ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```